# Should graduate students peer-review papers?

Tags: journals, peer-review, career-path

Why is being part of the peer-reviewing process beneficial for a graduate student?

Comment: @neuranna: I disagree. There is very little in the answers to that question on the benefits for the reviewer.

Comment: The title and the actual question don't match.

Comment: For general benefits, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/why-do-academics-write-peer-reviews.  And see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/should-i-agree-to-review-papers-as-a-postdoc for the same question about postdocs; all the same reasons also apply to grad students.

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20403/as-a-ph-d-student-should-i-spend-time-reviewing-papers?noredirect=1&lq=1 for an even more exact duplicate.