# How to supply proof that you are a reviewer for a journal?

Tags: peer-review, cv

How can you prove that you are a reviewer for a certain journal. For example, I have been invited to review a paper in a certain journal and on my CV I want to write that I have reviewed in this journal but since reviewers are supposed to be anonymous, how can I supply proof that I have reviewed in this journal?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reviewers normally receive a confirmation email from the journal editor after submitting a review online. Such email should be sufficient to prove that you have reviewed for the journal.

Comment: The emails are a bit sensitive, they include your username and login.

Comment: Not the emails thanking you for having submitted the review!

Comment: @user121692 This is not 100% relevant, but you should know that any website that is able to email you your actual password, not a link to reset your password, is not securely storing your password. I studied this in university, and just wanted to warn you. No website should ever store your password directly (it should be encrypted and irretrievable). I suggest using a different password for that site than all your other passwords, because it is extremely vulnerable.

Comment: Most time when you review a paper they send you a link that includes some sort of randomly generated limited time password and it's just valid for that paper you're reviewing.  This is a case where they decide that ease of use (you're volunteering to do this after all) is better than security.  It's likely that the password encoded in the link isn't valid shortly after you submit your review so I'm sure it's not a huge problem.

Comment: @Dan You're making a whole lot of assumptions. It's entirely possible (and even probable) that the password was generated, sent in the email, hashed (not encrypted as you wrote), and then forgotten while the hash was kept.

Answer (score 39):

You don't need to prove it. If someone thinks you're lying, they can just contact the journal editor and check. Reviewers aren't supposed be completely anonymous, anyway. It's just that no one outside of the editors should know who reviewed which articles.

Comment: I've seen universities ask for tenure-track faculty to submit documentation of reviews being submitted.

Comment: @aeismail That's a different matter from listing it in your CV.

Answer (score 27):

Some journals publish a "thank you to reviewers" list at the end of the year.  If your name is on such a list than that establishes that you reviewed for the journal.

As a practical matter, no one is likely to check your CV at this level of detail anyway.

Comment: I always think that people who post what they've reviewed in their CV are really stretching it and I think negatively about them because of it.

Comment: @Mark I disagree; a list of journals you have reviewed for in the recent past is useful information: a) a reasonably long list shows that you are a good academic citizen and, when hired, are likely to help shoulder the load; b) a *too* long list shows that you have difficulty saying no, and c) the quality of the journals on the list is some indication of who considers you an expert in your field. Of course, you need to distinguish between your public CV (e.g., what you'd put on your website) and the full CV (which you'd submit for an application); I'd only put this on the latter.

Comment: see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3540, especially StrongBad's answer.

Comment: FWIW I'mr required to provide a list of journals for which I've reviewed as part of my annual report for performance evaluation.  I don't include this information in the CV that I make available to others off campus.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any of the other documents by now, just write the publisher and ask him for a letter confirming your being a reviewer.