# May I mention in my CV that I am a reviewer for a journal if I co-refereed?

Tags: peer-review

Recently, a collaborator of mine received a paper to referee from a journal, and he proposed me that we review the paper together. When he submitted the report, he indicated to the journal that he reviewed the manuscript with me. Am I allowed to write in my CV that I am a reviewer for this journal?

Comment: Erm, the problem occurred when you collaborator asked you to referee the paper with you - this should not happen without the editors consent since your collaborator got the paper on a confidential basis. Probably the editor was fine with it, but this action should be indicated *before*.

Comment: Indicating it would be at least a bit dishonest. The only thing reason to indicate being a reviewer for a specific journal on your CV is that this is a (relatively) highly regarded journal and the fact that they asked you carries some prestige. But they did not in fact ask you, they asked your collaborator. Further, this is the sort of thing that is already borderline to put on a CV as it is not verifiable by others.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft *I refereed for journal X* is verifiable by contacting the editors.  Referees are anonymous for a specific article, but the list of names of people who refereed for a particular journal issue with dozens of articles is often public.  Agree that co-refereed is less prestigious and listing co-referee as referee is overstating, though.

Comment: @gerrit I had not really thought of that. Not being an editor, I have no idea if it would be considered "normal" to inquire about such things in my field (math).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I expect such an inquiry would not be usual, because if a potential employer/supervisor suspects that an applicant is lying about their achievements then there may be larger worries / alarm bells in the way of proceeding.  But I'm no editor either so I'm not sure (and I'm in a different field).

Answer (score 0):

You can list reviewer activities on your CV, especially in an early stage of your career, see e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/3543/68222.

The situation you describe is different. You weren't one of the official reviewers of the paper. As stated by @Dirk, this situation is uncommon and might not be compliant to the journal policies. Because of that, I suggest to not mention this specific *"review"* on your CV.