# pros and cons of accepting ORCID Reviewer Credit / Recognition

Tags: peer-review, digital-researcher-id

When submitting a review, some Publishers/Journals ask whether one would like to getting Reviewer Credit, by asking the following question

**ORCiD Reviewer Recognition**. *Publisher xyz* can send verification of this review directly to ORCiD. If you would like to take advantage of this service: 1. Please click on the “Yes” option below. 2. You will be asked to sign on/register with ORCiD. 3. The name of this journal and year of your submitted review will then be transmitted to ORCiD. 4. ORCiD will display this information as a verified item from Springer Nature on your unique ORCiD researcher profile

Please Select: Yes No

What are pros and cons of accepting (or refusing) this request?

Comment: This is a similar question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94541/publons-is-it-a-serious-thing

Answer (score 2):

Currently, peer review work is not widely rewarded by academic employers or funding agencies.  Publicly identifying yourself as a peer reviewer is publicly identifying yourself as someone who works for free.  You *might* get more requests for you to peer review if you do it.  It is also possible nobody will notice.

Otherwise, accepting or refusing the request is unlikely to do much.

You might wish to carefully examine your ORCID privacy settings.