# How does Clarivate incentivise journals to market Publons?

Tags: peer-review, publishers

I've observed that MDPI sends out an awful lot of emails marketing Publons to me as a peer reviewer.  I think they are not the only publisher to do so.  It seems to me that Clarivate/Publons is an indirect competitor to MDPI.  How is Clarivate getting MDPI to market for them?

Comment: I am not sure whether it really is _Clarivate_ that tries to market its _Publons_ via _MDPI_. My guess would be different. I could imagine that _MDPI_ tries to strategically put off its image as a non-serious publisher by displaying itself as a peer review-cherishing entity. And this commitment may seem more credible when _MDPI_ embraces _Publons_ so ostentatiously.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a point in trying to understand the e-mail activities of MDPI. They send an awful amount of e-mails dealing with all kinds of things, and I cannot see any strategy behind it that makes sense.

Comment: @anpami I do not see how association with the completely useless Publons benefits MDPI's reputation.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist How is Publons completely useless? I use it and recommend it to other postdocs because it helps me keep track of numbers of reviews and what journals, which is all part of the job hunting CV

Comment: @JenB https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94309/is-it-worth-creating-a-profile-with-publons Opinions vary.